# Parsing text with optional data at the end

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Please note, subsequently to posting this question I managed to derive a solution myself. See the end of this question for my final answer.

---

I'm working on a little parser at the moment for [org-mode](http://orgmode.org) documents, and in these documents headings can have a title, and may optionally consist of a list of tags at the of the heading:

```
* Heading          :foo:bar:baz:
```

I'm having difficulty writing a parser for this, however. The following is what I'm working with for now:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

data Node = Node String [String]
            deriving (Show)

myTest = parse node "" "Some text here :tags:here:"

node = Node <$> (many1 anyChar) <*> tags

tags = (char ':') >> (sepEndBy1 (many1 alphaNum) (char ':'))
   <?> "Tag list"
```

While my simple `tags` parser works, it doesn't work in the context of `node` because all of the characters are used up parsing the title of the heading (`many1 anyChar`). Furthermore, I can't change this parser to use `noneOf ":"` because `:` is valid in the title. In fact, it's only special if it's in a taglist, at the very end of the line.

Any ideas how I can parse this optional data?

As an aside, this is my first real Haskell project, so if Parsec is not even the right tool for the job - feel free to  point that out and suggest other options!

---

Ok, I got a complete solution now, but it needs refactoring. The following works:

```
import Control.Applicative hiding (many, optional, (<|>))
import Control.Monad
import Data.Char (isSpace)
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

 data Node = Node { level :: Int, keyword :: Maybe String, heading :: String, tags :: Maybe [String] }
   deriving (Show)

parseNode = Node <$> level <*> (optionMaybe keyword) <*> name <*> (optionMaybe tags)
    where level = length <$> many1 (char '*') <* space
          keyword = (try (many1 upper <* space))
          name = noneOf "\n" `manyTill` (eof <|> (lookAhead (try (tags *> eof))))
          tags = char ':' *> many1 alphaNum `sepEndBy1` char ':'

myTest = parse parseNode "org-mode" "** Some : text here :tags: JUST KIDDING     :tags:here:"
myTest2 = parse parseNode "org-mode" "* TODO Just a node"
```

Comment: How about first parsing the header to a lit and than marshalling the data into your struct?

Comment: Hi, I don't know what a "lit" is i'm afraid, but I still don't see how I can just parse the heading and ignore the tags, without consuming the tags section in my parser

Comment: Hi @ocharles, is the resulting org-mode parser actually present, are you sharing the code? I started to dig a little into haskell, and combining this learning with org-mode tinkering is somehow a pleasing thought. kind regards,

Comment: @TomRegner - not particularly, though there is some work on my GitHub: github.com/ocharles

Answer (score 1):

```
import Control.Applicative hiding (many, optional, (<|>))
import Control.Monad
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

instance Applicative (GenParser s a) where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap

data Node = Node { name :: String, tags :: Maybe [String] }
  deriving (Show)

parseNode = Node <$> name <*> tags
  where tags = optionMaybe $ optional (string " :") *> many (noneOf ":\n") `sepEndBy` (char ':')
        name = noneOf "\n" `manyTill` try (string " :" <|> string "\n")

myTest = parse parseNode "" "Some:text here :tags:here:"
myTest2 = parse parseNode "" "Sometext here :tags:here:"
```

Results:

```
*Main> myTest
Right (Node {name = "Some:text here", tags = Just ["tags","here",""]})
*Main> myTest2
Right (Node {name = "Sometext here", tags = Just ["tags","here",""]})
```

Comment: Looks great, but I can't seem to load it in my GHCI:  Illegal instance declaration for `Applicative (GenParser s a)'. I can fix this by removing the Application instance completely though. However, it still leaves the problem that "Heading : more text :tags:here:" doesn't parse :(

Comment: That looks neat, but could you please explain what exactly you are doing?

Comment: @ocharles don't paste directly into ghci - it can't handle certain bits of syntax. Save to foo.hs and then in ghci run ":l foo". You can have ghci pick up your changes afterward by running ":r" for refresh.

Comment: That was with :l Orgdex.hs. I think I have a different version of Parsec

Comment: @ocharles Yeah I think so too.